# Why this won't receive return value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this in my HTML code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var URL = replace(); 
    alert(URL);
</script>
```

If I put this in header, alert shows “http://example.com/result"

```
function replace() { 
　url = 'http://example.com'; 
　$.get(url, function(data){ 
　　var url_gen = data.responseText; 
　}); 
　return “http://example.com/result"; 
}
```

But if I use return like this, it won't do anything. Why?

```
function replace() { 
　url = 'http://example.com'; 
　$.get(url, function(data){ 
　　var url_gen = data.responseText; 
　}); 
　return url_gen; 
}
```

Just to make sure, If I insert **alert(url_gen)** in front of **return url_gen;** in 2nd code, alert shows 'http://example.com' so **url_gen** has an actual value in it!

Note: Here, assuming that **url_gen** is the string which is web-scraped from a web page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make url_gen global like below:

```
function replace() { 
url = 'http://example.com'; 
var url_gen ='';
$.get(url, function(data){ 
url_gen = data.responseText; 
}); 
return url_gen; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for an answer. I tried your code, but now the alert says "undefined" instead of showing url

Comment: It returns empty. as nicael said, $.get() is  async so  you should work or do necessary operation inside success callback.

Answer (score 1):

Because 1) `url_gen` only defined in `$.get()`, can't be accessed outside; 2) `$.get()` is async.

Workaround: return directly from `$.get()`:

```
function replace() { 
　url = 'http://example.com'; 
　$.get(url, function(data){ 
　  var url_gen = data.responseText; 
    return url_gen;
　}); 
　 
}
```

Comment: Thanks now alert says "undefined" :(

Comment: you receive undefined because you set alert on a response of ajax function. ajax has a delay to retrieve data but alert is triggered as soon as you call it. You have to make a sync ajax call (bad way because the window will freeze until your function is finished) or change your structure to set alert inside ajax response.